# select() function in tabs - Angular Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Look at [this](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) there  is tab component. In the tab setting there is:

```
select()
```

and

```
deselect()
```

I did not know how to use them.
I tried to reach them from js file using the $scope but it did not work

HTML

```
<tab ng-model="Tab1" ....>
```

js

```
$scope.Tab1.select();
```

but it does not select the content of that tab.

please help me in a way how can I select tab content from the javascript or in other meaning using $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood what that function is.

The `select` property of a tab is a function callback that is called when the tab is activated. What you are looking for is instead the `active` property, which refers to the boolean property that controls the activation of the tab.

```
<tabset>
    <tab select="alertMe()" active="Tab1.active">
        <tab-heading>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
        </tab-heading>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

So, in this example, you can do

```
$scope.Tab1.active = true;
```

And the tab will be activated. Upon activation, it will fire the function `alertMe` (in the example it displays an alert).

Comment: What I want is to display the content of the tab as I said in the last line in my post. I want the event to open the tabl as I click on it using mouse when another tab is shoing content/open/clickerd.

Comment: Yes. As I said, you have to bind that tab "active" property with some property (for example, Tab1.active). Then, when you use `$scope.Tab1.active = true` that tab will become active.

Also, the tab-heading does the same thing you want, it's just its default behavior.

Comment: Thank you for reply @XelharK. I understood your point, but I will appreciate your if you help me in my last explanation. I think I will edit my question also.

Comment: for your second reply, I can answer you that the tab is not opening as you click on it, it opens its content. That just makes it active. Did you get my point?

Comment: I want to show display the tab content not activating it based on an event @Xelhark

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Tabs display their content when activated. What are you trying to do then?